# View in frame XAML innitialization

Tags: xaml, mvvm, uwp, frame

I have XAML code to create program output in frame. I can change content of frame in case I used "MyFrame.Navigate(typeof(Setup))". Is there any way to initialize content of frame in XAML code?

XAML code fragment:

```
        </SplitView.Pane>
        <SplitView.Content>
            <Frame Name="MyFrame" ?any reference to view to first time intiilaization? />
        </SplitView.Content>
```

Thanks for help

Comment: What is it that you'd like to display? The Frame element is designed to display your app's pages.

Comment: I want place next XAML file in the frame. XAML with List of IP addresses and some action buttons for the record set. Record set contains columns - IP Address, Description, Status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SourcePageType`

It can set in xaml ,the code is

```
    <Frame Name="MyFrame" SourcePageType="Setup"></Frame>
```

The frame will navigate to `Setup`

I think you can use the control above in the Frame when you enter the page ,you can set it Visibility and you can set is hidden when load complete.

Comment: Thanks for help. I used this code

                <Frame Name="MyFrame" SourcePageType="BlankPage">

and message I received is "BlankPage is not supported in Windows universal Project"

Comment: For you have not BlankPage?

Comment: this is acceptable format
<Frame Name="MyFrame" SourcePageType="BlankPage">